# Is it possible to add optional arguments when running Rscript in terminal?

Tags: r, shell, sh

For now, what I use is just like:

```
Rscript myscript.R *arg1 arg2 arg3* ... >output.txt
```

However, I would like to show what the different arguments mean and create optional arguments, like:

```
Rscript myscript.R --project_ID *arg1* --input_package *arg2* --input "arg2" --output *output.txt*
```

In addition, some args are not required, for example, if --input_package is NULL, then argument of "arge2" in --input is not needed, but if the input_package is filed, the other argument will not be input.

Is this possible? If not, may I regardless of the indicating in command and only input the parameters in order? But some of them are optional??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`optparse`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/09/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/), and set default values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library("optparse")
 
option_list = list(
  make_option(c("-f", "--file"), type="character", default=NULL, 
              help="dataset file name", metavar="character"),
    make_option(c("-o", "--out"), type="character", default="out.txt", 
              help="output file name [default= %default]", metavar="character")
); 
 
opt_parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list);
opt = parse_args(opt_parser);
```

You can then check if i.e. the parameter `--file` (with default `NULL`) is provided like so

```
if (is.null(opt$file)){
  #dosomestuff
}
```